# How to inherit and prepend a field inside a group via xpath in Odoo?

Tags: xpath, odoo, odoo-14

I need to place a field as the first child of an existing group. I have ever used `position='before'`, `position='after'`, `position='inside'`, and `position='replace'`. None of them can achieve the result I desire.

I need something like this.

```
<xpath expr="//group[@name='partner_details']" position="prepend"></xpath>
```

Detailed explaination: Think of it as how `position='inside'` does to a field, but I want this to be placed at the beginning instead of at the end.

Anyone knows how to do this or any workaround that can achieve this?

======= UPDATE example according to Prophet's comment. ========

Example XML: I want to place my newly customized field before the `partner_id` without referring to the `partner_id` because it can be dynamic.

[image: example]

Comment: Instead of telling stories, can you present us some XML and describe what you need to do with it?

Comment: @Prophet See my updated example.

Comment: Thank you. Now it's clear but not something I'm familiar with ...

Comment: Have you tried `expr="//group[@name='partner_details']/*[1]" position="before"` which means put my node "before the first child of the group ..."?